# MouseEvent<HTMLElement> giving error Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mouseevent, react-hooks

I am converting a button component with `MouseEvent<HTMLElement>` in React to use Hooks. However, I am now getting an error of `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` on each mouse event.

The new code is

```
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);
  const [isFocus, setIsFocus] = useState(false);
  const [isHover, setIsHover] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (autoFocus && button instanceof HTMLButtonElement) {
      button.focus();
    }
  }, [autoFocus, button]);

  const isInteractive = () => !isDisabled && !isLoading;

  const onMouseEnter = (e: MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
    setIsHover(true);
    if (onMouseEnter && !isHover) {
      onMouseEnter(e);
    }
  };

  const onMouseLeave = (e: MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
    setIsActive(false);
    setIsHover(false);
    if (onMouseLeave && isHover) {
      onMouseLeave(e);
    }
  };

  const onMouseDown = (e: MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setIsActive(true);
    if (onMouseDown && !isActive) {
      onMouseDown(e);
    }
  };

  const onMouseUp = (e: MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
    setIsActive(true);
    if (onMouseUp && !isActive) {
      onMouseUp(e);
    }
  };

  const onFocus: FocusEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement> = event => {
    setIsFocus(true);
    if (onFocus) {
      onFocus(event);
    }
  };

  const onBlur: FocusEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement> = event => {
    setIsFocus(false);
    if (onBlur) {
      onBlur(event);
    }
  };

  const onInnerClick: MouseEventHandler<HTMLElement> = e => {
    if (!isInteractive()) {
      e.stopPropagation();
    }
    return true;
  };

  const StyledButton: ReactType = CustomComponent || getElement();
  render() {
    return (
      <StyledButton
        onMouseEnter={onMouseEnter}
        onMouseLeave={onMouseLeave}
        onMouseDown={onMouseDown}
        onMouseUp={onMouseUp}
        onFocus={onFocus}
        onBlur={onBlur}
      >
        {children}
      </StyledButton>
    );
  };
```

Whereas the original code is (that works)

```
state = {
  isActive: false,
  isFocus: false,
  isHover: false,
};

componentDidMount() {
  if (this.props.autoFocus && this.button instanceof HTMLButtonElement) {
    this.button.focus();
  }
}

isInteractive = () => !this.props.isDisabled && !this.props.isLoading;

onMouseEnter = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
  this.setState({ isHover: true });
  if (this.props.onMouseEnter) {
    this.props.onMouseEnter(e);
  }
};

onMouseLeave = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
  this.setState({ isHover: false, isActive: false });
  if (this.props.onMouseLeave) {
    this.props.onMouseLeave(e);
  }
};

onMouseDown = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.setState({ isActive: true });
  if (this.props.onMouseDown) {
    this.props.onMouseDown(e);
  }
};

onMouseUp = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
  this.setState({ isActive: false });
  if (this.props.onMouseUp) {
    this.props.onMouseUp(e);
  }
};

onFocus: React.FocusEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement> = event => {
  this.setState({ isFocus: true });
  if (this.props.onFocus) {
    this.props.onFocus(event);
  }
};

onBlur: React.FocusEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement> = event => {
  this.setState({ isFocus: false });
  if (this.props.onBlur) {
    this.props.onBlur(event);
  }
};

onInnerClick: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLElement> = e => {
  if (!this.isInteractive()) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  }
  return true;
};

const StyledButton: React.ReactType = CustomComponent || this.getElement();
render() {
  return (
    <StyledButton
      onMouseEnter={onMouseEnter}
      onMouseLeave={onMouseLeave}
      onMouseDown={onMouseDown}
      onMouseUp={onMouseUp}
      onFocus={onFocus}
      onBlur={onBlur}
    >
      {children}
    </StyledButton>
  );
};
```

What have I missed in the new code with hooks that is causing the `event` to repeat?

Comment: Where do you define the `autoFocus` and `button` variables that are in your `useEffect` dependency array?

Comment: Without being able to run this code myself, I'd say check those hook functions (e.g. `onMouseEnter`) and try to figure out if it's entering a recursive loop. For example, in `onMouseEnter` it calls itself `if onMouseEnter && !isHover`. I suspect at least one of those hook functions may be causing the issue. In my experience, the `maximum call stack size exceeded` has been the result of accidentally calling a function recursively with no exit condition.

Comment: @Nick `autoFocus` is defined in the `props` as `HtmlAttributes` in the `interface` of the type and default as `false` but with `type` `boolean. `button` is `const button: React.Ref<HTMLButtonElement> = React.createRef<HTMLButtonElement>();`

Comment: @MattU I suspected this too but even if I give `null` return outside of `if` I have the same result

Comment: @Darren have you tried commenting out those if blocks inside the hooks to see what happens?

Comment: @MattU Hmmm... no but that worked. The button and mouse events still work. It's almost as if I don't require `e: MouseEvent<HTMLElement>` and only need to `useState`. Why would that be?

Comment: I don't know a ton about React, so unfortunately I don't have a strong answer to your question. However, it does indeed sound like calling those functions again in the `if` blocks were causing infinite recursion. Sorry I can't tell you exactly why it works as you expect after removing those, I just figured those were somehow part of the problem.

Comment: @MattU. Thank you for your help. I have left the commented out and documented the reasons. We'll see over time as to whether this needs to be fixed or left out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is your use of useEffect. The two values you have provided for the deps Array in the useEffect is what I believe is causing the issue. The equivalent for componentDidMount which would be called once, is to have an empty array or no array at all.

This would mean changing your useEffect code to as follows

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (autoFocus && button instanceof HTMLButtonElement) {
      button.focus();
    }
  }, []);
```

The reason for this is if either of those values are changed the useEffect is called again, which would cause re-rendering and reevalation of button and autofocus (I Assume) which would then call useEffect again and thus cause infinite recursion.

More information can be found in the first example here https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks

Hopefully this helps :D 
Good luck!

Note: 
I didn't actually run your code, I am just assuming this is the issue